# Deleting an item in a list view

Tags: android

I am using a custom list view by extending the ArrayAdapter class. Each row has some text as well as an image. What I want to do is delete the row when I click on the imagevView. So i set an onclick listener as well as a tag for each image view and then used the onclick listener to change the adapter. However it simply refuses to work. What exactly am I doing wrong?

```
holder.image.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) 
                {


                    Toast.makeText(context, "ImageView clicked for the row = "+view.getTag().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    createEvent.list.remove(view.getTag());
                    createEvent.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
```

The toast prints correctly. However the item is not deleted. Any ideas on how I can achieve this?

Comment: Okay. I finally understood.I should call view.getTag() and convert it into an integer explicitly